# gem sqlite not load in gemfile rails 4

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

i using rails 4 and ruby 2.0, but when i running rails s i in console i get some error like this :

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:58:in `rescue in resolve_hash_connection': Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
```

why error? i alredy put gem 'sqlite3' in gemfile and run bundle install but still error, this my gemfile :

```
ruby '2.0.0'

source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'devise'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'carrierwave'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

group :development do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
# Use debugger
gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'pg', group: [:production]

gem 'rails_12factor'
```

and this my database.yml :

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

if i wrong please tell me?? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going into your gemfile.lock file and changing the sqlite3 version to `sqlite3 (1.3.8)` and then re-bundle install/bundle update